# Ubuntu 12.10 live-usb won't boot

Tags: boot, 12.10, live-usb

I own an Aleutia "Tango" low power PC. It uses a Intel Atom CPU N2800 @1.86GHz processor. I know there are Linux issues with the "Cedar Trail" graphics on this hardware but I can happily run Ubuntu 12.04 using the VESA graphics driver.

I wanted to try out Ubuntu 12.10 so I created a live USB under 12.04 but I am unable to get this to boot. It gets as far as the Grub screen but after that the monitor shuts down. I have tried the F6 "nomodeset" option but that doesn't make any difference.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this problem?

Thanks in advance.